# How old is this Forest Air Vertical Mounted air conditioner?

Tags: hvac

I am looking at a Forest Air Vertical Air Conditioner

- Model Number 13 - 04596
- Serial Number:  VK008 000A99 MQA2ESB 0025
- BATCH NUMBER:      K QA 2E.

**Would anyone be able to tell me when this was manufactured ?**

I went to that appliance website, but the Forest Air was not listed.

I will be inspecting the unit shortly.

Comment: The [user's manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/759048/Forestair-13-04596.html) has a copyright date of 2006. That *likely*, but not guaranteed, would be the oldest manufacture date.

Comment: This has been edited out now, but you mentioned you will be inspecting the unit. Often times, there will be a date of manufacture listed on the data plate attached to these types of devices.

Comment: That is important info, @PhilippNagel, so I put it back in, but in a less rude fashion.